# Зачем в Python нужен self если можно создать простую функцию и передать ей переменную

Tags: python

Вот здесь на сайте объясняется суть `self`: [Для чего в python нужен self?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1098214/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2-python-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-self/1489939#1489939)

Вопрос: зачем зачем создавать эти страшные конструкции типа `__init__` и `self` если указанная ниже функция выдаст тоже самое?

```py
def Dog(name):
   return f'Имя моей собаки {name}'

nick_name = Dog('Rex')
print(nick_name)
```

Comment: "а зачем нужно много компьютеров в университете, если все могут работать за одним"

Comment: Связанные вопросы: [Какой смысл имеют классы в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1131816/1365), [Когда использовать классы (ООП)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1042362/1365)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какой смысл имеют классы в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1131816/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bc%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-python)

Comment: @ n1tr0xs, такой комментарий не даёт мне ответ на вопрос. Указанная в моём вопросе функция принимает аргумент, который и принимает все компьютеры, а не один

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- А что вы будете делать, когда от `Dog` вам нужно будет не одно свойство получить, а два, десять, сто свойств? Будете писать сто отдельных функций? Будете писать одну мега-функцию с параметром, в котором будете передавать, какое свойство вы хотите получить или изменить?
- А если вы захотите от `Dog` каких-то действий, зависящих от его внутреннего состояния? Например, у него есть уровень сытости и вы хотите, чтобы он по-разному гавкал в зависимости от этого уровня?
- А если вы захотите иметь несколько разных `Dog` с разным состоянием - вы будете это состояние хранить где-то снаружи и передавать в ваши функции каждый раз вручную?

Просто нужно чуть продолжить мысль о том, что вам может понадобиться от класса и как этим всем было бы удобно пользоваться - и тогда необходимость инкапсуляции, т.е. включения/скрытия полей (переменных) и методов (функций) внутри класса и его объектов, придёт к вам сама собой.

Собственно, `self` как-раз и представляет собой собой ссылку на объект класса, на его состояние.

А конструктор `__init__` нужен, чтобы в удобной форме задать первоначальное состояние экземпляра объекта. Например, имя для собаки. Вряд ли это имя поменяется в течении жизни объекта "собака", так что очень удобно задать это имя сразу при создании объекта. Так исторически и возникла необходимость в конструкторе класса.

И так со всеми штуками, относящимися к классам. Если начать разбираться, то все они нужны как-раз для удобства программиста.

Comment: Полностью соглашусь с ответом уважаемого CrazyElf, но дополню последнюю фразу "... при условии, что программист создает большой и сложный проект". А вот попытки тулить ООП где надо и не надо - действительно могут только усложнить код. Просто новички как правило и имеют дело с простенькими задачками-проектами, поэтому им сложно даже представить, что будет, если "нужно будет не одно свойство получить, а ....., сто свойств"